# BASH script stop after executing one line but if I use echo instead of exec the output of the script completes

Tags: bash, sox

Background
I am a newbie to Bash scripting and through Googling I have got as far as I have.

I have two text files:
"Filemp3.txt" that contains

songname - artist.mp3

songname2 - artist2.mp3

songname3 - artist3.mp3

and Fileogg.txt that contains

songname - artist.ogg

songname2 - artist2.ogg

songname3 - artist3.ogg

I will be using SOX to convert from MP3 to Ogg.

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<Fileogg.txt

while read mp3; do
        read -u3 ogg
        echo sox "Musicmp3/$mp3" "Musicogg/$ogg"
done <Filemp3.txt
```

This outputs exactly the commands I want to run line by line.

```
radio@radio:~$ ./convert-mp3-ogg.sh
sox Musicmp3/songname - artist.mp3 Musicogg/songname - artist.ogg
sox Musicmp3/songname2 - artist2.mp3 Musicogg/songname2 - artist2.ogg
sox Musicmp3/songname3 - artist3.mp3 Musicogg/songname3 - artist3.ogg
```

But when I edit the script to exec e.g. exec sox "Musicmp3/$mp3" "Musicogg/$ogg" ... the script runs & an ogg file is created but for only the first filename.

I am assuming this is a problem with my Bash script as the ogg file plays fine and Sox does not show any error I am aware of.

Comment: Why not just use the one file of sources and do "sox Muxicmp3/$mp3 Musicogg/${mp3%mp3}ogg" - use the input file name but change the extension for the destination? Or do you have some cases where you want to convert `x.mp3` into `y.ogg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exec` command *replaces* the command being executed in the current process with a new command. It's like a subroutine call that never returns. In this case, you simply want to call `sox`, and continue after it returns, so just drop the `exec`:

```
while read mp3; do
    read -u3 ogg
    sox "Musicmp3/$mp3" "Musicogg/$ogg"
done < Filemp3.txt
```

Comment: Pedantically, `exec` replaces the current *program*, the process is the same.

Comment: Thank you chepner that worked a treat - also thanks to others with the same answer and explanation

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated meanings of `exec`, which is probably where you are confused.  The first one you use:

```
exec 3<Fileogg.txt
```

is fine, it opens *file descriptor* number 3 for file 'Fileogg.txt', and is read with your `read -u3`.

There is a second use of `exec` though, and that is to replace the current *program* with a different one, in the same process.  There is no return from a successful `exec`.  So when you:

```
exec sox "Musicmp3/$mp3" "Musicogg/$ogg"
```

that replaces `bash` with `sox`, so you never return to the script!

Just remove the `exec`, you don't need it here:

```
sox "Musicmp3/$mp3" "Musicogg/$ogg"
```